# need to replace localhost:3000 with realip:3000 in composer-rest-server

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have uploaded the composer-rest-server on AWS machine , i have managed to launch without errors the composer-rest-server , although it always refer to http://localhost:3000 , i want to change my localhost to my actual host ip on AWS

can someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your REST server available on an IP or domain resolvable hostname ie on an available network interface such that other REST clients can consume it.

Its likely your REST server (accessed through Explorer) is already listening on 0.0.0.0:3000 and hence listening on all configured interfaces (on your server). For REST server deployment more info here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server.html

the parameter in your COMPOSER_DATASOURCES to change (if you need to change it) is here (straight out of loopback basically):

```
 COMPOSER_DATASOURCES='{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "host": "mongo",
    "ip": "10.99.98.x"
  }
}'
```

referenced here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server.html

Comment: I have gone the steps in the reference that you have mentioned , also i have added the public ip address of my AWS server after checking that i can ping it , yet still my browser can not connect to it

Comment: Hi, Have you found solution?