# Hyperledger-Composer-Rest-Server - REST API public

Tags: rest, hyperledger-composer

Is there any way to run the Rest-Server of Hyperledger Composer on another IP/Network than running on a localhost-port ?

Comment: see this Stack Overflow -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179869/need-to-replace-localhost3000-with-realip3000-in-composer-rest-server

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also use Nginx reverse proxy to re-route all the traffic to `localhost:3000`. Try this in your Nginx configuration file

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Be sure to replace `example.com` with the correct IP / domain and restart Nginx using `sudo systemctl restart nginx`. If you are running Ubuntu, the settings above should be saved to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf`.