# HyperLedger composer exposing Rest server to outside world

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have deployed deployed the .bna file and even created rest server endpoints in my vm using composer-rest-server. I would like to expose these API to outside world? What should be done to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this link -> [need to replace localhost:3000 with realip:3000 in composer-rest-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179869/need-to-replace-localhost3000-with-realip3000-in-composer-rest-server)

Obviously you could use port forwarding so that when your users hit your VM at  http://nn.nn.nn.nn:3000/explorer (ie VM has an extra network interface with fixed IP address, that is accessible by the 'outside world')  - it will forward that to the REST server running in your VM.  Obviously no authentication/REST wallets set in this example.

Comment: Thank you!!I was able to access it